net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found), can't solve video play in background
I try to add video in the background of the main slider. 
Make Video Background In Website Using React.
Problem: react net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).
picture of code #1
picture of code #2
I have set:
{
    (property) videoBg: string
    videoBg: "main-slider-1-1.mp4",

This is my code:
const SingleSlide = ({ slide = {} }) => {
const { videoBg, image, title, socials } = slide;
return (
<SwiperSlide>
<div>
<video src={videoBg) autoPlay loop muted />
</div>
<div className="main-slider_social">
{socials.map(({title, href}, i) => (
<a key={i} href={href)>
[title]
</a>
))}
</div>
<Container>


Please post SingleSlide.js as text, rather than an image (maybe after the sentence "This is my code" rather than before the prior sentence). It could also help if we see the parameters being supplied to the SingleSlide function.

@SnehalGhanekar. Welcome to StackOverflow. You're new, so be aware that on this forum it is preferred to post code as text (because code in pictures cannot be tested).  You can use edit options to add code text into your Question. The current text is auto-extracted from pictures (and will have some OCR mistakes).
